# Meteor (blaze) how to find all values from a select multiple

Tags: html, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a multiple dropdown (`<select multiple>`), and I want to find all the values. I can recover the first one by using the `target.event.element.value`.

How can I grab them all without using jquery?

Comment: What's wrong with using jQuery? It's already added to your app and available to you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with jQuery I'd just wanted to know it there was any way to do so with just meteor "sintax". To keep the code as consistent as posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is already there for you.

If you really want to use anything else, try:

- `this.findAll()`, read more about it here http://meteor.github.io/blaze/docs.html#template_inst
- native `document.querySelectorAll()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Here's an [example of all three in meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/bMgb9HAc8nAqH3svz/FindSelectedOptions), but seriously - jQuery is your friend for DOM retrieval.  It's already loaded!  If you go to use `template.findAll()` it's just wrapping jQuery anyway with a scope of your current template.

Comment: I've got nothing against JQuery!, I was just wondering if there was a better solution specific for meteor.